# Transposing a column values into column headers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
+-------------+-----------+------------+
| sample_name | test_name | test_value |
+-------------+-----------+------------+
| s1          | t1        | 1.5        |
| s2          | t2        | 3          |
| s3          | t1        | 8          |
| s4          | t3        | 5          |
+-------------+-----------+------------+
```

And I want to put the test_names as column headers like this

```
+-------------+------+------+------+
| sample_name |  t1  |  t2  |  t3  |
+-------------+------+------+------+
| s1          | 1.5  | null | null |
| s2          | null | 3    | null |
| s3          | 8    | null | null |
| s4          | null | null | 5    |
+-------------+------+------+------+
```

I have come up with a convoluted solution using a temporary table, dynamic sql and while loops
but its slow and would like to know, is there a way to do it with only a select?

thanks

Comment: You should post your solution (or a minimally working example of it) to get specific answers. You are unlikely to get an answer to an open-ended question like this is currently written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if there are too much values for `test_name` then you may use ***pivot***  within ***dynamic sql***:

```
declare @Names varchar(max) 
select @Names = coalesce(@Names + ', ', '') + test_name 
from (select distinct test_name from tbl) t

exec('
SELECT *
FROM tbl t
 PIVOT (SUM(test_value)
        FOR Test_name 
        IN ('+@Names+'))p')
```

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/513ced/3)

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisLavigne , you're welcome, you can accept this answer if helped or solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/2294)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(sample_name VARCHAR(10), test_name VARCHAR(10), test_value DECIMAL(10,2))
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES 
 ('s1','t1',1.5),        
 ('s2','t2',3  ),        
 ('s3','t1',8   ),      
 ('s4','t3',5  )


SELECT *
FROM @Table t
 PIVOT (SUM(test_value)
        FOR Test_name 
        IN (t1,t2,t3))p
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/2294/0)**:

```
| sample_name |     t1 |     t2 |     t3 |
|-------------|--------|--------|--------|
|          s1 |    1.5 | (null) | (null) |
|          s2 | (null) |      3 | (null) |
|          s3 |      8 | (null) | (null) |
|          s4 | (null) | (null) |      5 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)s which do that exact thing.  They're most useful if there's a finite number of `test_name` values, but they can be used even if those values aren't known in advance.